# LINQ - How to select and count the right results

Tags: linq

I have 3 tables: DiaryPosts, DiaryImpressions, Impressions.

Impressions is a small list with some fields: 'like', 'dislike', 'agree', 'disagree'. The user can vote according to what he thinks about the post.

DiaryImpressions is the table that handles the relationship between the posts and the users who vote.

My problem is, I have to count results of each impression vote for each post, so maybe for one post 13 users voted for like, 2 for dislike, 34 agree and 1 disagree.

I have no idea how to perform the query in some way I can get this specific count results for each impression.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Please show us the variables you have and how they are made.  We make something up but that does not help if it is different

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.groupby.aspx) method.  It allows you to automatically "group" the elements based on the impression, and count the results per group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Reed Copsey, could you give me any example? I never used that one before =)

Comment: @RubiaGardini It depends on your types more than anything. I'd look at the 101 LINQ Samples for good examples of using GroupBy: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

```
var post(from c in posts selec c)

string post1like;
string post2dislike;
string postagree3;
string postdisagree3;


foreach (var item in posts)

{
  var ipressionslike=(from c in imressions where impressioid=item.id where c.impressionID='LIKE' select c.userID).Tolist()
   var ipressionsdislike=(from c in imressions where impressioid=item.id where c.impressionID='disLIKE' select c.userID).Tolist()   
  var ipressionslike=(from c in imressions where impressioid=item.id where c.impressionID='LIKE' select c.userID).Tolist()
   var ipressionsagree=(from c in imressions where impressioid=item.id where c.impressionID='disLIKE' select c.userID).Tolist()  
post1like+=item.id+""+ipressionsdislike.count;
post2dislike+=item.id+""+ipressionslike.count;
postagree3+=item.id+""+ipressionsagree.count;
}
```

it should count the impressions for each post and count the amount of users that like or dislike so if you have 30 people dislike for each post it should get them I cannot see your table structure but I hope it will help or point you somewhere

Comment: Thank you @COLD TOLD, if I can't realize how group works by myself, I'll skip that and use your example for sure, it make my mind really clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess but here is what I think the SQL would look like:

```
SELECT I.Name, COUNT(I.Name)
FROM DairyPosts P
JOIN DairyImpressions DI ON P.ID=DI.DairyID
JOIN Impressions I ON DI.ImpressionsID = I.ID
```

And what the linq would look like:

```
List<Dairy> dairyposts = GetDairyPosts();
var impressionCounts =
    from p in dairyposts
    group p by p.ImpressionName into g
    select new { Type = g.Key, ImpressionCount = g.Count() };
```

Of course I have to assume your list is created a certain way, if you can post how your list is actually created that would help.  (As I said in the comments)

Comment: I couldn't do that, if I try this line/; SELECT i.Impression, COUNT(i.Impression) MSSQL throws a message: Column 'Impressions.Impression' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I just posted another question with more specific information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073817/linq-how-to-select-group-and-count-results

Comment: @rudia gandini - for you first comment add a group by i.name to the end